# PowerShell, use Sort-Object to return an Array

Tags: arrays, powershell, sorting, sort-object

I've looked at various sites that suggest that `Sort-Object` will return an array. This is not what I am seeing as when I do the below, the final output caused by the `Sort-Object` is just a single string. How can I sort the array into another array instead of to a string?

```
$myprogs = Get-ChildItem D:\MyPath\MyPrograms
$myprognames = foreach ($i in $myprogs) { $i.FullName -replace "D:\\MyPath\\MyPrograms\\", "" }
# At this point, $myprognames is a normal array
$myprognames = $myprognames | Sort-Object -Unique
$myprognames
# At this point, $myprognames is a single string with all elements stuck together, and if I select an element, like $myprognames[17], I will just get a single character as it's a string.
```

Comment: When I do the `$i.FullName`, that's just a string, so I'm creating an array of strings, right? Hence, I just want to sort the strings out into an ordered set of strings and save them as an array. The strings themselves are the set of objects that I want to sort alphabetically. i.e. I'm basically throwing away all of the properties that the Get-ChildItem returns and just want the `.FullName` strings. I don't see what you mean about not saving my changes, sorry?

Comment: Updated my answer. Take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I assume right you want something similar to this:

```
$myprogs = 
    Get-ChildItem 'D:\MyPath\MyPrograms' |
        Select-Object -Property *,
            @{Name = 'ShortenedPath'; Expression = {$_.FullName -replace ([regex]::escape('D:\MyPath\MyPrograms'))}}
$MyProgNames = $myprogs | 
    Sort-Object -Property ShortenedPath -Unique
```

Of course you should list all properties you're actually after instead of using `-Property *`

According to your comment you're actually looking for the names of the folders sorted, right? If that's the case you're overcomplicating this a lot. ;-)

```
$myprogs = 
    Get-ChildItem 'D:\MyPath\MyPrograms' |
        Select-Object -Property Name |
           Sort-Object -Property Name -Unique
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a specific reason for doing this, but didn't want to complicate the question. I need only the names in this way, because I am collecting target paths of shortcuts from a different system that have different relative paths to my local folders and that include the target executable in the names of that side, so I first want to strip off the exectuable, *then* strip off the common prefix part of the path (`D:\MyPath\MyPrograms`) and *then* sort those simple strings. You are right that the `Name` property correctly fits the question as I asked it. 

Comment: Do you know why my array of strings in the OP is getting stuck together into a single string instead of sorting into another array of strings when I use `Sort-Object` on it (my preferences is that the the array is opened up, sorted and then a new sorted array is created)?

Comment: Actually no. And I cannot reproduce this behaviour. I get the output I'd expect from the code.